# Error with a Google Doc in Google Classroom ... cannot open

Tags: google-classroom

[image]

I have a Google document that students add to every week. They have their own copy each. It essentially replaces their normal exercise book in school. I am trying to access one of these documents through Google Classroom but it does not open. It simply looks like the attached image. All of the other documents are working. What do I do?

We desperately need this document restored as it contains months and months of work.

Thank you for your help.

Timmy Goodall

Comment: Hello Timmy, did you contact the google support? Here is the [link](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047213)

Comment: Apparently I need to use MY ADMINISTRATOR account ... my school email does not work. They do make this whole process so incredibly difficult! Thank you for the help!